# I can't seem to get rails installed on my Mac (10.6.5). Following Ruby on Rails Tutorial 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to get Rails 3 up and running by following the steps outlined in "Ruby on Rails Tutorial" by Michael Hartl (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book).

The details start in section 1.2.2 (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#sec:rubygems).  Here you go through the following steps:

1. Installing Git
2. Installing Ruby (version 1.9.2) using Ruby Version Manager (RVM)
3. Creating different gemsets for environments using Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2
4. Installing RubyGems

and finally, installing Rails.

I run the following command [sudo] gem install rails --version 3.0.7

Everything seemed to install correctly (based on no errors).  However, when I type "rails -v", rails cannot be found.

I am a Rails newbie.  I'm trying to install Rails on a machine running Mac OS X 10.6.7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RVM you probably don't want to use `sudo` when installing gems.  If you have Git installed only steps needed to get Rails are:

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.zshrc
# Reload your shell now (open a new terminal for example)
rvm install 1.9.2
rvm 1.9.2 --default
gem install rails --version 3.0.7
hash -r
```

This skips the gemsets part (you don't need it if you are just starting learning Rails) and assumes that you use Zsh (I think it's Mac OS X default, if you use Bash then you have to alter `.bashrc`, not `.zshrc`).

If you want to remove your previous installation and start over use `rvm implode`.